# `cargo build-sbf` doesn't work on linux

Tags: error, build-bpf, cargo

I consistently get this error message when running `cargo build-sbf` or `cargo build-bpf`
[image: error messages]

```
Warning: cargo-build-bpf is deprecated. Please, use cargo-build-sbf
cargo-build-bpf child: /home/anish/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/cargo-build-sbf --arch bpf
/home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo: /lib/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo)
/home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo: /lib/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo)
/home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo: /lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo)
/home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo: /lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo)
```

```
/home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/sbf/bin/cargo: /lib/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/sbf/bin/cargo)
/home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/sbf/bin/cargo: /lib/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/sbf/bin/cargo)
/home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/sbf/bin/cargo: /lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/sbf/bin/cargo)
/home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/sbf/bin/cargo: /lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /home/anish/.rustup/toolchains/sbf/bin/cargo)
```

The files `/lib/libssl.so.1.1` and `/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1` do exist (although symlinks)

[image: libssl and libcrypto files]

Would be helpful if someone can help me troubleshoot this

OS: Pop! OS 22.04 (based on Ubuntu 22.04)

Edit:
`openssl version` output -
[image]
v1.1.1q

Answer (score 1):

`Sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`
Do this might work (not sure)

Comment: It is already installed